# Android: Listening to AAC+ files generated by StreamRipper

Tags: android, aac

I ripped a ShoutCast broadcast (that streams AAC+) using StreamRipper (to listen on the phone when offline). StreamRipper (a Windows program) produced files with the "AAC" extension that play fine in Windows (Winamp, VLC, MediaPlayer, etc). However, these files do not play on Android (4.1) - tried Music Player and Music Folder Player. The format is unrecognized.

How do I play these files on an Android smartphone?

Answer (score 0):

Whereas there doesn't seem to be an Android-related solution, Android will play these AAC streams if they are packaged into an MP4 container.

To package an AAC file into an MP4 file (without any transcoding), use ffmpeg with the following command-line switches:

```
ffmpeg -i {input_file.aac} -vn -absf aac_adtstoasc -acodec copy {output_file.mp4}
```

(where "-absf aac_adtstoasc" is required for ffmpeg to parse the AAC file properly).

On Windows, the following batch file will find and process all AAC files found in the current directory, and place the resulting MP4 files in the same directory:

```
for /f "usebackq delims=|" %%f in (`dir /b *.aac`) do "c:\Program Files\ffmpeg\bin\ffmpeg.exe" -i "%%f" -vn -absf aac_adtstoasc -acodec copy "%%f".mp4
```

(your path to ffmpeg may differ).